# Excel table conversion help needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Here is the current table:

[image: Here is the current table]

I would like it to look like this:

[image: How table should be formatted]

As you can see in the original table, some people don't have data (paid up) for the categories of "rent" "late", "utilities", etc.

I have tried `vlookup` and it works okay, but I can't get the data per person without changing the array table per person.

Comment: Create a new sheet. The data in your first image would could be sheet "Data" and the new sheet could be "Totals". In Totals you would set A2=Data!A2 which would be Bob. B2=Data!C2+Data!C3+Data!C4[etc...] which would output 1,500. For utilities, you just grab the data for utilities, same for late fees, and so on to break those down like you have in your second image. Basically a sheet for inputting all of your data and a sheet which grabs all of that data and makes it readable.

Comment: I don't see how your two tables are related. Names and data seem quite different.

Comment: Ignore the names @RonRosenfeld its the format that is important

Comment: I also don’t see how your two tables are related.  None of the numbers in the second table are traceable to the first table in any obvious way.  (The fact that both tables contain “0.00” doesn’t count, because the zeros in the first table are associated with Sally, who isn’t in the second table.)  It’s bizarre that the first table has a person (Sally) who isn’t in the second table, and the second table has four people who aren’t in the first one.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And, after pointing out that some people (*again,* e.g., Sally) are prepaid and don’t have itemized (categorized) charges, you don’t say or show how such people should appear in the second table.   (And, BTW, from a real world point of view, I don’t see why a creditor wouldn’t compute and keep itemized records of the charges of people who are prepaid.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMIFS` instead of lookups, very powerful and flexible. The range would be the column with values, and you add two conditions, one for the person, the other for the type of charge.

The only change you need to do is to populate each line of your dataset with the appropriate name of the person. This you can easily automate with a formula as well of course.
Once you have a clean dataset, you also can use pivot tables, but I personally prefer to make my own summary with `SUMIFS`.

[Interesting article](https://professor-excel.com/when-to-use-vlookup-sumifs-or-indexmatch-in-excel/) with a comparison of SUMIF , LOOKUP , and INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: Wouldn't SUMIFS give you the sums of count data with multiple criteria? I need the actual value for each criteria per person.

Comment: @user3105519 The `SUMIFS` gives you sum of the data, and it works also if there is only one occurrence (i.e. one value to be summed). It is the `COUNTIFS` function that counts the occurrences that match the conditions.